# MongoDB command `compact` is not working

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

I have a collection of documents in which I store an array of numbers. This collection is replenished with new documents about every 10 seconds. Every day I run a script which handles this arrays and leaves in documents only one number. After 3 month of data collecting I want to release disk space. Here is stat info of the collection from Robomongo:

```
{
    "ns" : "orderbook",
    "count" : 5363208,
    "size" : 844457120,
    "avgObjSize" : 157,
    "storageSize" : 2795139072.0,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
        }
    }
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 144482304,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 90615808,
        "date_1" : 53866496
    }
}
```

As you can see the storageSize is much larger than the size. I expect that command `compact` will release disc space.

What I do in mongo shell:

```
use trading
db.runCommand({compact:'orderbook', force: true})
```

The answer is

> { "ok" : 1 }

Logs from /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log:

> 2016-12-26T11:19:55.468+0300 I COMMAND  [conn7] compact trading.orderbook begin, options: paddingMode: NONE validateDocuments: 1
>
> 2016-12-26T11:19:55.562+0300 I COMMAND  [conn7] compact trading.orderbook end

Nothing happens. storageSize has the same value.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: v3.2.11. Also, I've tried `db.repairDatabase()` command. Same result.

Comment: Are you able to share a gist/pastebin/... with the full output of the collection `stats()`? It looks like you've redacted most of the WiredTiger details. Have you changed any WiredTiger options from the defaults (and if so, can you provide details)? Lastly, what sort of deployment is this (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster)?

Comment: Here you are: [stats](https://gist.github.com/krabradosty/37730bb3ca00cced9225087e92b5c2af)

Comment: No, I changed nothing. All settings are default. It's standalone instance on my ovh server

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue, did manage to solve yours? Thanks

Comment: Yes, make a backup and then restore your data. This will release disk space. Also after these actions, `db.repairDatabase()` will work properly.